# username:pwd@url in IE 9 doesn't work even after registry edit and security zone changes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, http-authentication, browser-automation

This is a sort of a URL which I need to use to automate my application using Selenium RC, 
http://user:pwd@somedomainname.domain.com.

My question: Is this format really supported by IE 9? I can see it works perfectly in FF. 
This works same in IE with the `webdriverobject.get("url")` method, but what happens in RC?

### Things I did to fix

1. Change of security settings identical to all zones.
2. Added the iexplore to 0 in regedit. MS fixit didn't work either.
3. Spent almost a day googling for solutions.

Nothing worked.

### Stack trace

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Failed to navigate to http://demo:demo@snarain0d1.ptcnet.ptc.com:28000/Windchill/app/?forceTrail=true. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 50 milliseconds
>
> Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>
> System info: host: 'SNARAIN0D1', ip: '132.253.12.169', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
>
> Session ID: 7790e5d1-daaf-4c1f-b359-672d2104b13b
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>
> Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer does not support username & password in URL.
Refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

To handle authentication popup in IE you have to use third party tool like AutoIt or Robot class. I tried it successfully using java Robot class:

```
driver.get("http://www.test.com");
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("password");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.sendKeys("username");
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 try {
 (new Robot()).keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  (new Robot()).keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  } catch (AWTException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
}
//alert.accept();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: You can use alert.accept() instead of these lines of code  try {
 (new Robot()).keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  (new Robot()).keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  } catch (AWTException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
}